# Can't load Action Helpers in Zend-framework application

Tags: zend-framework, helper, autoload

I'm trying to create an Action Helper, but I'm havin't a hard time loading it and I'm getting this error:

`Message: Action Helper by name Usersession not found`

In my controllers action method, where i'm trying to call this helper, I have this:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath('/helpers/');
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Helper');
$userSession = $this->_helper->getHelper('Usersession');
$this->view->session = $userSession->eendersWat();
```

I'd actually prefere to load my helpers from bootstrap.php, but wasn't able to figure that out neither.

My helpers are located in `application/controller/helpers`. My helper filename is `Usersession.php` and the class is called `Helper_Usersession`

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like the following in `Bootstrap`:

```
protected function _initHelperPath()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers',
            'Application_Controller_Action_Helper_');
}
```

The helper class is then named `'Application_Controller_Action_Helper_Usersession'` and the file is located in `application/controllers/helpers/Usersession.php`

Of course, this presumes you are using `Application_` as your application namespace. In your case, it appears that you are using an empty application namespace and none of my wordy `Controller_Action_` infix, so your's would be something like:

```
protected function _initHelperPath()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers',
            'Helper_');
}
```